# Loading reference data in spring batch from a file

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I want to pre-load some reference data from an input file (CSV) as one of the initial steps (preload-references).   The following steps will read the main input file with data that needs to be processed.   Each record to be processed will need to lookkup data loaded in the preload-references step.   How can this be done?!   Can reference data be passed into main Processor routine along with the data Record?

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of simplicity - may we assume that you need a job with two steps and that the first step will pass data to the second step? If this is the case you may try to:

1. Store the data into the `ExecutionContext` of step 1.
2. "Promote" this data into the next step with the help of an `ExecutionContextPromotionListener`.
3. Consume the data into step two.

I'll back up my words with a very naive example partially inspired by the [official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/patterns.html#passingDataToFutureSteps).

In step one we are "reading" values:

```
class Step1Reader implements ItemReader<String> {

  private AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

  @Override
  public String read() throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException, ParseException, NonTransientResourceException {

    long cnt = counter.incrementAndGet();

    return cnt > 5 ? null : String.valueOf(cnt);
  }
}
```

Then "processing" them by appending the current time in millis at the end:

```
class Step1Processor implements ItemProcessor<String, String> {

  @Override
  public String process(String item) throws Exception {

    return item + "~" + System.currentTimeMillis();
  }
}
```

Finally outputting them into the standard output and storing some junk in the context (I'll leave out the multithreading concerns):

```
class Step1Writer implements ItemWriter<String> {

  private StepExecution stepExecution;

  @Override
  public void write(List<? extends String> items) throws Exception {
    items.forEach(System.out::println);
    Integer hashCode = (Integer)stepExecution.getExecutionContext().get("key");
    stepExecution.getExecutionContext().put("key", hashCode == null ? items.hashCode() : hashCode + items.hashCode());
  }

  @BeforeStep
  public void saveStepExecution(StepExecution stepExecution) {
    this.stepExecution = stepExecution;
  }
}
```

This should output something like:

```
1~1505055135727
2~1505055135727
3~1505055135727
4~1505055135727
5~1505055135727
```

So far so good. Next step is to "promote" the key:

```
  @Bean
  ExecutionContextPromotionListener executionContextPromotionListener()
  {
    ExecutionContextPromotionListener ret = new ExecutionContextPromotionListener();
    ret.setKeys(new String[]{"key"});
    return ret;
  }

  private Step step1() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
        .<String, String> chunk(10)
        .reader(new Step1Reader())
        .processor(new Step1Processor())
        .writer(new Step1Writer())
        .listener(promotionListener)
        .build();
  }
```

In the second and even more naive step the value can be accessed like this:

```
class Step2Writer  implements ItemWriter<String> {

  private Object obj;

  @Override
  public void write(List<? extends String> items) throws Exception {
    items.forEach(s -> System.out.println(s + "~" + obj));
  }

  @BeforeStep
  public void retrieveInterstepData(StepExecution stepExecution) {
    JobExecution jobExecution = stepExecution.getJobExecution();
    ExecutionContext jobContext = jobExecution.getExecutionContext();
    this.obj = jobContext.get("key");
  }
}
```

Hope that helps :-)

Comment: Lachezar - thank you for this detailed example.   Yes, I also imagined Step 1 - load the Reference data items.  Step 2, process main input data.   For each input record, lookup the reference data loaded in Step1.    Run through some business logic.  

The only thing that concerns me is that I need to store about 6-7000 such reference entries.    What I would really like to do in Step1 is to build a collection of objects and make that available to Step 2 processing.  How can I do that?

Comment: _Example:_
Step 1 - read Contract data from an input file, set up a collection and pass it to  next step.  
Step 2 - read billing data from input file, for every billing item read from input, process it, by looking up Contract data loaded in Step 1, execute business logic,   Write data out to db table.
I can almost think of this as a Merge of two data sets:   Main data set (billing) and 2nd data set (Contract).   The processing routine needs to access both of these data sets to execute business rules.

Comment: @JamesD: In the context of my example - just build and store whatever you want in the Step1Writer: stepExecution.getExecutionContext().put("key", ..). In Step2 you can already access this collection (for example) through the Job's Execution context as shown in Step2Writer, which is Bean.

Answer (score 0):

Store a large amount of data into `StepExecutionContext` is not recommend because this context is serialized to SB metadata tables and you will get a data truncation error if data is too large.
Instead of preload data you can access this data using a specific DAO and put access requests under cache: no need to slow preloading and memory consumption will grow accordlyng to your job.
You will also gain restartability.

Comment: >>using a specific DAO and put access requests under cache<< - could you share an example of the cache solution?

Comment: Google for 'using cache with spring' (for example) and you'll find a lot of interesting link about spring cache module